# AngularJS ng-repeat set font color

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code

```
<div ng-repeat="cat in filteredTodos">
   <input class='inputIsActive' type="checkbox" ng-checked="{{cat.isActive}}"/>
   <span>{{cat.isActive}}</span>
</div>
```

isActive can have `true` or `false` value. How to set the `<span>` font color basing on the `isActive` value ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.filteredTodos = [{
    isActive: true
  }, {
    isActive: false
  }];
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
.inactive {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="cat in filteredTodos">
    <input class='inputIsActive' type="checkbox" ng-checked="{{cat.isActive}}" />
    <span ng-class="{ active: cat.isActive, inactive: !cat.isActive }">{{cat.isActive}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or use [`ng-style`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.filteredTodos = [{
    isActive: true
  }, {
    isActive: false
  }];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="cat in filteredTodos">
    <input class='inputIsActive' type="checkbox" ng-checked="{{cat.isActive}}" />
    <span ng-style="{color: cat.isActive ? 'green' : 'red'}">{{cat.isActive}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Edit

And with `ng-model` instead of `ng-checked`:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.filteredTodos = [{
    isActive: true
  }, {
    isActive: false
  }];
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
.inactive {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="cat in filteredTodos">
    <input class='inputIsActive' type="checkbox" ng-model="cat.isActive" />
    <span ng-class="{ active: cat.isActive, inactive: !cat.isActive }">{{cat.isActive}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it works, but now how to dynamically change that font color if I uncheck any checkbox ?

Comment: use `ng-model` for binding the `isActive` value, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span style="color: {{cat.isActive? 'green' : 'red'}}">blue</span> eyes.</p>
```

This may work

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ng-class` or `ng-style`

```
<span ng-class="{'active' : cat.isActive , 'not-active' : !cat.isActive}">{{cat.isActive}}</span>

 .active { 
     color:green;
 }

.not-active { 
     color:red;
 }
```

---

```
<span ng-style="{color: (cat.isActive ? 'green' : 'red' )}">{{cat.isActive}}</span>
```

here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6f69VNZhFGxZba2Mlh5Y?p=preview)